# c# integer validationRule unit test

Tags: c#, validation, unit-testing

I need to write a unit test to test if the input is a valid integer value. I have tried several ways, but i don't think it's the correct way to test for currency value.

TEST CASE:

```
namespace validationUnitTest
{
    // Validation rule for checking if the input is a valid integer value

    public class IntegerValidationRule: ValidationRule;
    {
        private static ValidationRule validationRule;

        /// Singleton instance of this <see cref="ValidationRule"/>

        public static ValidationRule Instance { get { return validationRule ?? (validationRule = new IntegerValidationRule());  } }

        // performs validation checks on a value

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value is long) return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            string stringValue = value as string;
            Long result;
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue) || long.TryParse(stringValue, NumberStyles.Integer, cultureInfo, out result) ? ValidationResult.ValidResult : new ValidationResult(false, "Value must be an integer");
        }
    }
```

}

UNIT TEST:

```
namespace validationUnitTest.Tests
{
[TestClass()]
public class IntegerValidationRuleTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ValidateTest()
    {
        var test = new IntegerValidationRule();

        var expected = new ValidationResult(true, 3);

        var actual = test.Validate("0", null);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected.ErrorContent, actual.ErrorContent);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.IsValid, actual.Isvalid);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.GetHashCode(), actual.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

}

ANY idea on how I should start my unit test, or what I should be search for? I need some starting points. Any thing is greatly appreciate.

Comment: `idea on how I should start my unit test` <= what do you mean by this? Do you mean how to execute your unit test? Also shouldn't you get the instance with your static singleton pattern? `IntegerValidationRule.Instance` instead of `new IntegerValidationRule()`? If you only want access via the singleton then you forgot a private constructor.

Comment: Instead of comparing the properties of `expected` and `actual`, you should be able to use simply `Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);`.

Comment: @wimh i did that but it give an error

Comment: @igor i should but I don't know how

Comment: `I should but I don't know how` <= That still does not answer the question, help me help you. Do you need help with (pick one or both) **A)** Not sure how to execute/run your unit tests or **B)** Need help with the code inside your unit tests (as in not sure if the code is correct).

Comment: @igor unfortunately A and B

Comment: In visual studio you can use the Test Explorer. See [Run unit tests with Test Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First, your validate method is only checking whether or not the number is a valid `double`, not if it's actually an valid integer. It also returns true if the value is a double, which is not what you're asking it to do. You should take advantage of the [`int.TryParse(string, int)` method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would rewrite your validate method to look something like:

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(string value)
{
    int number;

    bool isValid = int.TryParse(value, out number);

    return isValid 
        ? ValidationResult.ValidResult 
        : new ValidationResult(false, "Value must be an integer");
}
```

As for your unit test, I would just take some various string values and assert that they come back as valid or not. You don't need to run the method for your "expected" value, because you already know if your test values are valid integers or not.

```
var actual = test.Validate("0");
Assert.IsTrue(actual.IsValid);

actual = test.Validate("foo");
Assert.IsFalse(actual.IsValid);

// Repeat ad nauseum with different values
```

Comment: Sorry i update the test case. It was supposed to be long instead of double. But your unit test is simple and make sense. Thank you

Comment: @Addiction006 Make sure you change the names of the class and methods then, so they're descriptive of their behaviour. Also, there is a `.TryParse()` method for doubles and longs as well. And if this answer solved your issue, accept it if you like! :)

Comment: I can't change my test case. But im using your test and it worked